# Transform a .fo file to .pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to convert a **source.fo** file to a **result.pdf** file in Java.

I'm looking for the same result than invoking the Apache Fop command:

```
fop -fo source.fo -pdf result.pdf
```

Maybe is not an important fact for the question, but I've managed to create those .fo files using freemarker templates, and in all the examples i found on Google using the java fop library, they create the pdf using an xml and a xsl-fo files, and is not my case.

My B plan (that I'm trying to avoid) consists in calling the system command.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you read [FOP: Embedding](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/embedding.html)? Any questions left then? (I'm only calling it on cmdline, but can't imagine that they don't document your use case reasonably too)

Comment: I guess not, but that's  all I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A - Sample Fo file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" language="EN">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="5mm" margin-left="5mm" margin-bottom="5mm" margin-top="5mm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" master-name="A4-portrail">
            <fo:region-body margin-bottom="20mm" margin-top="25mm"/>
            <fo:region-before precedence="true" display-align="before" extent="25mm" region-name="xsl-region-before"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrail">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:table border-style="solid" border-width="0.4mm" border-color="black" font-size="10pt" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(20)"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(45)"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(20)"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="2mm" display-align="center" text-align="left">
                            <fo:block>1299Levent Divilioglu</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell display-align="center" text-align="center">
                            <fo:block font-size="150%">
                                <fo:basic-link external-destination="http://www.example.com">List of Month Records</fo:basic-link>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block space-before="3mm"/>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="2mm" display-align="center" text-align="right">
                            <fo:block>19. Mayis Mah. No: 6 Kadikoy/Istanbul</fo:block>
                            <fo:block space-before="6mm" display-align="before">Page <fo:page-number/> . <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="end-of-document"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow reference-orientation="0" border-collapse="collapse" flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>Records of Month</fo:block>
            <fo:table space-after="5mm" display-align="center" text-align="center" border-style="solid" border-width="0.35mm" border-color="black" font-size="10pt" width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(20)"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(30)"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(25)"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)"/>
                <fo:table-body font-size="95%">
                    <fo:table-row height="8mm">
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Date</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Called Number</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Price</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>Discount Type</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>03-10-2016:19:25:03</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>505-999-88-77</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>12.95</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>4</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>08-10-2016:20:13:35</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>507-666-42-23</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>24.45</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>1</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>15-10-2016:17:47:34</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>535-234-44-54</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>21.34</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>3</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>21-10-2016:21:31:23</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>542-323-43-58</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>51.35</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block>2</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            <fo:block id="end-of-document">
                <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="150mm" width="200mm">
                        <path style="fill:yellow;stroke:red;stroke-width:2" d="M153 334 C153 334 151 334 151 334 C151 339 153 344 156 344 C164 344 171 339 171 334 C171 322 164 314 156 314 C142 314 131 322 131 334 C131 350 142 364 156 364 C175 364 191 350 191 334 C191 311 175 294 156 294 C131 294 111 311 111 334 C111 361 131 384 156 384 C186 384 211 361 211 334 C211 300 186 274 156 274"/>
                    </svg>
                </fo:instream-foreign-object>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

#### B - Sample Code

```
package com.levent.fop;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ConvertFoToPdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        hede();
    }

    public static void hede() throws SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        // Step 1: Construct a FopFactory by specifying a reference to the configuration file
        // (reuse if you plan to render multiple documents!)
//      FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("D:/output/fop.xconf"));
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());

        // Step 2: Set up output stream.
        // Note: Using BufferedOutputStream for performance reasons (helpful with FileOutputStreams).
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/output/myfile.pdf")));

        try {
            // Step 3: Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

            // Step 4: Setup JAXP using identity transformer
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); // identity transformer

            // Step 5: Setup input and output for XSLT transformation
            // Setup input stream
            Source src = new StreamSource(new File("D:/output/input.fo"));

            // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

            // Step 6: Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
            transformer.transform(src, res);

        } finally {
            //Clean-up
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

#### C - Sample Output

[image]